# Is there any other place than The Chill in Skyrim with unsummoned atronach?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am making an atronach replacer for Skyrim and I need to test whether my mod replaces all atronach summoned by another NPC or unsummoned (already placed as a monster in the map). Is there any other place or place where they get are scripted to appear without a NPC casting it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Flame Atronachs](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Flame_Atronach_(Skyrim))** can be found

> - roaming Skyrim and in dungeons occupied by conjurers, or during random encounters.

**[Frost Atronachs](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Frost_Atronach_(Skyrim))**:
Apart from *The Chill*,

> - one can be in the summoning chamber of [*Cragwallow Slope*](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Cragwallow_Slope) if at an high enough level,
> - three can appear in The Caller's chamber in [*Fellglow Keep*](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fellglow_Keep) during the College of Winterhold's questline.
> - Otherwise, Conjurers, Thalmor Wizards and Draugr Scourge mages have the ability to summon the atronachs.

**[Storm Atronachs](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Storm_Atronach_(Skyrim))**

> - can be found in the wilds, and are also commonly summoned by Dragon Priests.

---

Considering this, it'd be easier to 'summon' a couple of Dragon Priests and conjurers using the console:
Type `player.placeatme <BaseID> <#>`, where '`<BaseID>`' is `00023A93` for Dragon Priests, `000728AD` for Thalmor Wizards, `00023BF7` for Draugr Scourges, and `0001091A` for Arch Conjurers. '`<#>`' is the amount of NPC's you want to place.
Be sure to toggle God Mode with `tgm` :)

You might also want to check whether the standard Atronachs have been replaced using this console command: `00023AA6` is for the Flame Atronach, `00023AA7` for the Frost variant, and `00023AA8` for the Storm Atronach.